# Display a page in an iframe from a diferent domain

Tags: visualforce, iframe, cross-domain, reflected-xss, content-security-policy

I am trying to build a simple visualforce page with an iframe.

my page:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:iframe src="http://my.website.com" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
</apex:page>
```

- ("my.website.com" is a placeholder name for this question)

i have added the url to the "remote site settings" and checked the "Disable Protocol Security" box.
When trying to preview the page i get a **blank page** and the following errors:

1. Content Security Policy: Referrer Directive ‘origin-when-cross-origin’ has been deprecated. Please use the Referrer-Policy header instead.
2. Blocked loading mixed active content “http://my.website.com/”
3. Content Security Policy: Not supporting directive ‘reflected-xss’. Directive and values will be ignored.

Can anyone shed some light on what i need to do next in order to get the iframe to display in my page?

Comment: You have to set `X-Frame-Options` in header in the webpages in   `my.website.com `. Salesforce setting won't work.

Comment: Adding "Header always unset X-Frame-Options" to the ".htaccess" file in my "public_html" folder did the trick. If you want to add this as an answer i can mark it as correct

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I have added my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with Salesforce platform. You have to set `X-Frame-Options` in the header in the web pages in `my.website.com`. Salesforce setting won't work for this issue.